# Update the variable of sliderState after setting new min, max values

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, spring

Sorry, I'm begginer in js, I want to update sliderState after changing min, max of the slider.
I've functions which update min, max in slider, also I have the variable which is calculated from min, max.
I need update to this variable.

```js
  
   const sliderStates = [
        {
            name: "low",
            tooltip: "Great, we're confident we can complete your project within <strong>24 hours</strong> of launch.",
            range: _.range(state.minValue, state.maxValue / 3)
        },
        {
            name: "med",
            tooltip: "Looks good! We can complete a project of this size within <strong>48 hours</strong> of launch.",
            range: _.range(state.maxValue / 3, (state.maxValue / 3) * 2)
        },
        {
            name: "high",
            tooltip: "With a project of this size we'd like to talk with you before setting a completion timeline.",
            range: _.range((state.maxValue / 3) * 2, state.maxValue + 1)
        },
    ];
  //update min
    connector.updateMin = function (min) {
        let attributeMin = {
            min: min,
        };
        $element.attr(attributeMin).rangeslider('update', true);
    }
    //update max
    connector.updateMax = function (max) {
        let attributeMax = {
            max: max,
        };
        $element.attr(attributeMax).rangeslider('update', true);
    }
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code too

Comment: ```    $(element).html("<div class=\"main\">\n" +
        "  <input\n" +
        "      type=\"range\"\n" +
        "      class=\"slider\"\n" +
        "      name=\"participants\"\n" +
        "      id=\"rangeId\"\n" +
        "      min=\"1\"\n" +
        "      max=\"100\"\n" +
        "  >\n" +
        "  <span class=\"rangeslider__tooltip\" id =\"range-tooltip\"></span>\n" +
        "<div class=\"mydiv\"></div> \n" +
        "</div> \n"
    ); 
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/alexey-sherstobitov/pen/BaWjdGQ

Comment: main reason is what I wanna correcly uptade  color of handle after setting new min, max values